# Get ID value that references foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Background: I am using MySQL with InnoDB as the engine and PDO to execute the SQL.

I am new to foreign keys, but I have a `customers` data table which contains a `suffix_id` field, the `suffix_id` field in this table references an `id` field in a `suffix` data table. The reason I was told to do this is that there will most likely be duplicate values for suffixes for names and that having the foreign key constraint should improve the performance.

What I don't understand is how to get the `id` value from the `suffix` table. The only way that I know how to is to perform a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `suffix` WHERE `description` = ?
```

And then passing the value from that query to my "real" query as a separate command like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM `customers` WHERE ... AND `suffix_id` = [value from earlier query]
```

But to me, this seems inefficient to run two separate commands. Is there another way to get the id value that the foreign key is supposed to reference in the same query as my "real" query?

Comment: What are you really getting in the `suffix` table, the `description` or the `id`?

Comment: I am searching for the description, and so I would need to get the id from the suffix table in order to include it in my where clause on my customers search.

Comment: No wonder the flow looked reversed, you are using it for searching. What is the content of `description`?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.id
FROM `customers` a INNER JOIN `suffix` b ON a.suffix_id = b.id
WHERE suffix_id = some_value;
```

You'll want to lookup the concept of JOINS which are used to combine tables: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: OP is looking for a way to get the `id` to be used as value in `suffix_id`, which is quite different from your answer. OP will have nothing to put as value in your `WHERE` clause

Comment: No, this was exactly what I was looking for. I apologize if I did not word my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing a search, you will likely need [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp), and you can also combine those two query into one:

```
SELECT customer.*
FROM customer
    INNER JOIN suffix ON suffix.id = customer.suffix_id
WHERE suffix.description LIKE ?
```

It will be up to you how strict `LIKE` will be.